# PHP repeating forms validation. How to validate using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a repeating form. I have added validation to the forms with java script but I have to enter information in the first form before the other forms validate. I would like each validation process separate on each form. I have tried many different ways and all have failed. Thanks

PHP/html code below:

```
    $prodid = $row['id']; 



echo'<tr class="notetr3">';
echo '<form action="insertlink.php" method="post" name="' . $prodid. '" onSubmit="return newchoose1(' . $prodid. ')" >';
//first column (Company name)



echo '<td><select name="companyid" id="companyid"><option value="">Select Company</option>';
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM company
        WHERE id NOT IN
            (SELECT DISTINCT companyid FROM joincomppro WHERE productid = '$prodid')

"); //select productid that matches productid table

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $compid = $row['id'];
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    $sqlcompany2 = mysql_query("SELECT * from company WHERE id = '$compid'");   
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlcompany2)){
        $companyname = $row['companyname'];

        if ($num_rows) {

            echo '<option value="' . $compid . '">' . $companyname . '</option>';
        }
    }
}
echo '</select></td>'; 

//Second column (Batch size)
echo '<td><input type="text" value="Batch Size" name="batchsize" id="batchsize" size="17" maxlength="40"/></td>';
//third column (Batch price)
echo '<td><input type="text" value="Batch Price" name="batchprice" id="batchprice" size="17" maxlength="40"/></td>';

//fourth column

echo '<td><input type="text" value="Unit Price" name="unitprice" id="unitprice" size="17" maxlength="40"/></td>';

//hidden value

$groupselect3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE categorysubtype = '$categorysubtype' AND productname = '$productname' AND colour = '$colour'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($groupselect3))
{  
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="productid" id="productid" value="' . $row['id'] . '"/>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="groups2" id="groups2" value="' . $group . '"/>';
}
//submit
echo '<td><input type="submit" name="' . $prodid . '" value="Submit" /></td></tr>';

echo '</form>';
```

I then have JavaScript function as shown:

```
function newchoose1(id) {


    var emptyvalue = ""; 

    if (document.getElementById('companyid' + id).value == "") {
        emptyvalue += "Select a Company \n";
        }
    if (document.getElementById('batchsize' + id).value == "") {
        emptyvalue += "Enter a batch size \n";
        }       
    if (isNaN(document.getElementById('batchsize' + id).value)) {
        emptyvalue += "Batch Size has to be a whole number \n";
        }

    if((document.getElementById('batchprice' + id).value == "Batch Price" ) && (document.getElementById('unitprice' + id).value == "Unit Price")){

            emptyvalue += "Enter a number in Batch Price or Unit Price \n";

        }
    else if ((document.getElementById('batchprice' + id).value == "Batch Price") && (isNaN(document.getElementById('unitprice' + id).value))){

        emptyvalue += "Unit price has to be a valid number \n";

        }
    else if((document.getElementById('unitprice' + id).value == "Unit Price") && (isNaN(document.getElementById('batchprice' + id).value))){

            emptyvalue += "Batch price has to be a valid number \n";

            }
    else {}


    if  (emptyvalue != "") { 
        alert (emptyvalue);  
        return false;        
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to add `$prodid` to each form element control (e.g., "companyid") to ensure that each form control is unique and can thus be found by JavaScript. Then just include that `$prodid` inside your call to `newchoose1()`.

Something like this:

```
echo '<form action="insertlink.php" method="post" name="' . $prodid. '" onSubmit="return newchoose1(' . $prodid . ')" >';

// ...

echo '<td><select name="companyid" id="companyid' . $prodid . '"><option value="">Select Company</option>';
```

...and:

```
function newchoose1(id) {
    // ...
    if (document.getElementById('companyid' + id).value == "") {
    // etc....
```

Another approach would be to similarly pass `$prodid` to `newchoose1()` but instead of changing form controls, you would change the IDs inside the form to classes and then grab the element with the given class inside the specific form (I would recommend switching to jQuery to make your life simpler in this regard). This would also have the benefit of allowing you to present the same form controls with the same styles across different forms.

Comment: Thanks, with the first approach you suggested. Do you mean "companyid. $proid . ' or just int he arguement? and also how would I call in the javascript. I'm having a stupid moment as I still cant get to work.

Comment: beautiful. Thank you, looks so straight forward now. I couldn't understand how the PHP is passed into java script in that manner without changing each Id within the form. Many thanks Brett for your time

Comment: Hi Brett I tested your approach but the form does not validate at all now. I have edited above to what I have done, for some reason the Bold and Italics are not showing correctly. Guess you cant bold code text. (stars either side) :-)

Comment: Why don't you put on jsfiddle.net the resulting source code so we can see your output to make it easier for our testing. In Firefox, you can see it via ctrl-u (or from the menu, Tools->Web Developer->Page Source).

Comment: You also need to update each HTML element so that each element in the form has the same number appended to its ID...

Comment: Thank you once again Brett. It works perfectly and I should have noticed the error you brought to attention in your last post. Can i recommend you somehow or give you a thumbs up on stack flow? Regards

Comment: No need, Paul. You will need more privileges in order to give points beyond marking an answer correct, but by having done the latter, you have already assigned me some points. Anyways, am glad I could help. Have fun on StackOverflow...